Error #65 when express a uint_16 variable with the binary value in Keil IDE
I'm trying to express a uint16 variable in its binary representation in Keil IDE. But when I compile it gives me the error #65: expected a ";".
How can I pass a binary value to a uint16 variable?
You can find my code here:
uint16_t TX_Buffer;
int main(void)
{
  
  while (1)
  {         
            TX_Buffer = 0b1110110000000101;
            ... // My Code
  }
}


Binary notation is not standard C until the upcoming C23 standard. Are you sure that the compiler supports it? If not, then no can do.

Hexadecimal would be more conventional.
